# Using js to hide a div on click of aherf

Tags: javascript, jsp

I needs to hide a div when the aherf got clicked where I can't use script tag in it . So how can I do it.

```html
<div class="alert">
<p class="alert_message">alert</p><br>
<div><a herf=""class="hide">close</a></div>
</div>
```

Help me in this....

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  This community is great, but to get high quality answers you have to post well-formed questions.  I'd recommend reviewing [ask]

Comment: better you share your code for better help

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the [`onclick` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick) for the anchor element inline like this.

```html
<div class="alert">
  <p class="alert_message">alert</p><br>
  <div><a href="#" onclick="document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';return false;" class="hide">close</a></div>
</div>
```